# How to make simple GUI graph with Linear Equation

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, numpy, matplotlib

I am a beginner programmer. I have a task to make a GUI with a linear equation `y=mx+b` and a set of parameters where I can change the m and b values. I have both matplotlib and numpy. I also have tkinter for the GUI. This is what i have so far i edited my friends code on a coordinate GUI.

```
 def onButtonValChange():
    if X1.get() != '':
        x[0] = float(X1.get())

    if Y1.get() != '':
        y[0] = float(Y1.get()


def createGraph(x,y):
    graphRoot = Tk.Tk()
    graphRoot.wm_title("Your Graph")
    graphRoot.resizable(0,0)
    f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot(x, y)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=graphRoot)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

x = [1]
y = [1] 
ButtonChangeValues = Tk.Button(root, text="Submit Change", command=onButtonValChange)
ButtonChangeValues.grid(row=11, columnspan=3)

ButtonCreateGraph = Tk.Button(root, text="Create This Graph", command=lambda: createGraph(x, y))
ButtonCreateGraph.grid(row="15", columnspan=3)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a GUI instead of a static graph? look into `matplotlib`.

Comment: I was told to make this on a simple GUI interface because i will go further into making more complex things from this simple linear equation GUI

Answer (score 0):

So here is some code that i use its a moving line graph but you could adapt the code to move only when you change the equation. all you would have to do is populate the lists of x0Coords y0Coords and xy0Coords with the right mx+b formula

```
# Run from IDLE or LXTerminal not IDLE 3
# for import spidev to work, must run as python (v2) not python3

from Tkinter import * #to run on python 2, use Tkinter, for python3 use tkinter
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import spidev

#--------------------- variables -------------------------
#---user defined settings
screenWidth = 450
resolution = 5 #number of pixels between data points, for visual purposes only
samplePeriod = 100 #milliseconds, time between data points written to txt file
timeRange = .5 #minutes
#---end user settings

baseTime = int(timeRange*60*1000/screenWidth)
startTime = datetime.now()

nl = "\n"
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("500x300") #widthxheight

C = Canvas(root, bg = "gray", height = 250, width = screenWidth)


x0Coords = []
y0Coords = []
xy0Coords = []

coordLength = int(screenWidth/resolution)

#---initiation of lists
for i in range(0,coordLength):
    x0Coords.append(i*resolution)
    y0Coords.append(125)
    xy0Coords.append(0)
    xy0Coords.append(0)

#putting X and Y corrdinites in a list
def coordinate():
    global x0Coords, y0Coords, xy0Coords
    for i in range(0,coordLength*2,2):
        xy0Coords[i] = x0Coords[i/2]
        xy0Coords[i+1] = y0Coords[i/2]
    #print(xy0Coords)
#---End initiation of lists


c0 = C.create_rectangle(0,0,20,50)
cl0 = C.create_line(xy0Coords)
pressure = Label(root, text="test")
pressure.pack()

spi_0 = spidev.SpiDev()
spi_0.open(0, 0)

#--------------------------- End of Variables -------------------------

#--------------------------- Definitions ------------------------------

#shifts y values down in index in array to represent time moved forward
def shiftCoords(nextValue):
    global y0Coords, xy0Coords
    y0Coords.pop(0)
    y0Coords.append(nextValue)
    coordinate()

#updates the GUI based on the new time
def move_time():
    global c0,cl0,xy0Coords, resolution, baseTime
    C.delete(c0)
    C.delete(cl0)
    c0 = C.create_rectangle(0,0,20,int(float(readadc_0(0))/1023*250))
    shiftCoords(125-int(float(readadc_0(0))/1023*125))
    cl0 = C.create_line(xy0Coords)
    #print(float(readadc_0(0))/1023*250)
    root.title("V= " + str(round(3.3*float(readadc_0(0))/1023,2)))
    root.after(baseTime*resolution,move_time)

C.pack()
root.after(baseTime,move_time)
root.after(samplePeriod,writeData)
root.mainloop()
```